# ADB logcat exit on tag

Tags: android, adb, logcat

Im trying to filter android logcat at real time and execute some command or exit from logcat when specific tag occured. I tried the following:

```
adb shell "logcat | grep 'sometag' && echo 'Tag occured'"

adb shell logcat -m --regex='sometag'
```

In second command -m does not work at all, but is listed in logcat documentation.

Any ideas how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer (maybe temporary because infinite loop is not a best idea):

Because i'm scripting in PowerShell i found that solution:

```
While(1) {
    $log = & $abdPath shell "logcat -d | grep 'onPause'"
    if($log) {
         break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for down voting without any reason :)